# Group of units of a non-finitely generated ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am wondering, can a non-finitely generated ring have a finite group of units? If so, what are the examples?

Answer (score 3):

Consider maybe the the polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[X_1,X_2,\dots]$ with infinitely many indeterminates. This ring is not finitely generated and the only units are $\pm 1$.

Comment: Great example. (If I'm not mistaken, you can replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by any reduced ring $R$ whose unit group is finite too.)

Comment: @Alex I think it has to be an integral domain. There can probably be polynomials that are units if $R$ has zero divisors.

Comment: @MattSamuel: if $R$ is a commutative unital ring, then the units of $R[X]$ are those polynomials whose constant term is a unit, and whose higher terms have nilpotent coefficients. Hence, if $R$ is reduced, then $(R[X])^{\times}$ can be identified with $R^{\times}$. I am pretty sure a simple induction argument then shows that $(R[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}])^{\times} = R^{\times}$ for $R$ reduced, since we can view $R[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}]$ as $(R[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n-1}])[X_{n}]$. I don't think infinitely many variables poses a problem either, since any two elements of $R[X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots]$...

Comment: ...must live in some subring in finitely many variables, so if $f, g \in R[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{k}] \subset R[X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots]$ such that $fg = 1$, then $f,g \in (R[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{k}])^{\times} = R^{\times}$. I'd welcome any corrections if you see some mistake I've made!